# p:fileUpload not working

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I am having an issue with primefaces fileupload control. When i triggered the fileupload event my action listener is not being called . If i view the browser net tab i am seeing status code 405 as shown below.

[image]

My pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <springsecurity.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
    <jdk.compiler.version>1.8</jdk.compiler.version>
    <org.jsf.version>2.1.13</org.jsf.version>
    <org.primefaces.version>6.0</org.primefaces.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Junit Test --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jsr303 validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.1-b08</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SLF4J/Logback -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

     <!-- JSF -->
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
       <version>${org.jsf.version}</version>
       </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
       <version>${org.jsf.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
       <version>1.2</version>
     </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces -->     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${org.primefaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- File Upload -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR - 330 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>common</param-value>
</context-param>
<!--    Picture upload Filter Config Start -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
</filter-mapping>
<!-- Listner -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- Listner -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

MY JSF PAge

```
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <h:outputLabel for="ID" value="ID Copy:" />
        <p:fileUpload id="ID" fileUploadListener="#{candidateController.upload}" required="true" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"   sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="1" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" >
            <f:attribute name="ID" value="ID" />
        </p:fileUpload>

        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
    </h:form>
```

My Controller Class

```
@Component

public class CandidateController implements Serializable {

    public String upload(FileUploadEvent event) {

    // code     

    }

}
```

Spring security Configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/secure/home").access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")
        .antMatchers("/secure/**").access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")
        .antMatchers("/newuser/**", "/delete-user-*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/edit-user-*").access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository).tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
        .and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}

@Bean
public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices("remember-me",
                                                                                                          userDetailsService,
                                                                                                          tokenRepository);
    return tokenBasedservice;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver() {
    return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
}

}
```

Anybody have a look and advise what basic mistake I'm making?

Comment: i am not getting any error log in browser console. As my listner is not called when i hit upload so no server log for this action

Comment: The first thing you should try: Use recent versions of `commons-fileupload` (You have: 1.3.1, available is: 1.3.3 - no big deal), but `commons-io`: You have: 1.3.2 (**10 years old!**), but available is: **2.6**!) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io

Comment: So, did the upgrade solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved after modifying **web.xml** and **pom.xml** files as following.

1. web.xml

   ```
    I have changed the context param "primefaces.UPLOADER" from 'common' to 'native'.

   <context-param>
     <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
     <param-value>native</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```

2) pom.xml

```
    I have replaced the below dependency [org.apache.commons]

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        with [commons-io]

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

So after using the correct dependencies along with correct context param primefaces.UPLOADER filter it got resolved.
Plus thanks to below blog as well.

http://javaonlineguide.net/2015/07/file-upload-in-jsf-primefaces-5-2-example-simple-advanced-mode.html